# Symmetric chained decryption not working when decrypting twice the same cipher

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

I am working on creating the symmetric encryption chains in JavaScript which can encrypt the message using multiple different encryption algorithms (eg. *AES-DES-RC4*). It was working just fine when I stumbled across a problem when trying to decrypt the same cipher twice.

I am using [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) library and when trying to decrypt the cipher for the second time it either throws a `Malformed UTF-8 data` error or returns an empty string.

Here is my code:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

function createChain(chainName: string) {
  const algos = chainName.split('-')
  return {
    encrypt: (content, key) => algos.reduce((cipher, algo) => CryptoJS[algo].encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(cipher), key).toString(), content),
    decrypt: (cipher, key) => algos.reverse().reduce((message, algo) => CryptoJS[algo].decrypt(message, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8), cipher)
  }
}

const chain = createChain('DES-RC4-Rabbit-AES')
const message = 'test message'
const key = 'secret key'
const cipher = chain.encrypt(message, key)
console.log('Cipher:', cipher)
const l = 4
const decrypted = new Array(l).fill(0).map(() => {
  try {
    return chain.decrypt(cipher, key)
  } catch (e) {
    return e.message
  }
})
decrypted.forEach((d, i) => {
  console.log(`decrypted[${i}]=${d}`)
})
```

And here is my output:

```
Cipher: U2FsdGVkX19ENJVFoh1O1Y3RLTVph2k9eo1/bXxR9ccraZ912MDu7/PF+jJ0eSbSN060hIMudtO4J2J7YyADhQBIV5cTpFQIuKRkY9MZeh8ZC51RY+t7QdR/CSqWLzWjyUlaA8Lp02eAnf6xdnfiezbeiOrwo97WhHPRAcwVJMVuvN3K0L4xbWT+JOG6c1JY
decrypted[0]=test message
decrypted[1]=Malformed UTF-8 data
decrypted[2]=test message
decrypted[3]=Malformed UTF-8 data
```

As you can see it works alternately when I am trying to decrypt the same cipher. I have tried decrypting it more than 4 times, resulting with the same pattern.

What I have observed:

- If the chain is "symmetric", meaning it uses the algorithms in the same order forwards and backwards (for example: *AES-TripleDES-Rabbit-TripleDES-AES*), this problem does not occur.
- I have tried using the IV and PBKDF2 with hashed password as salt, with no effect.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The encryptions themselves seem to work. It appears to be more of a bug in the lamda expression that fills the array. When the array is filled correctly, the intermediate ciphertexts are displayed correctly, s. e.g. online on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/54fodm7e/

Comment: @Topaco yes you are right, the intermediate ciphertexts are filled correctly when running it one time, but when you try to run this function again, it breaks and either throws `Malformed UTF-8 data` error or returns an empty string. Take a look at [this fiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/sboa7drm/)

Comment: The cause is the `algos.reverse()` call in the decrypt branch. This reverses the order with each call. Remedy is a copy, e.g. `algos.map((x) => x).reverse()...`, s. https://jsfiddle.net/x251n3z0/

Comment: @Topaco oh my god you are right, thanks a lot!